# Panoply does not give polar stereographic feature

Tags: panoply

I have NetCDF data that I want to plot in polar stereographic format in Panoply. However my Panoply does not give me all the features. I am using Panoply in Windows 11. Can someone help me with that? I installed Panoply on Linux as well but still do not get all the features of the software.
The information of my data is:

```
float snow_cover_extent(time=682, y=88, x=88);
long_name = "Monthly Climate Data Record of snow cover extent";
comment = "Percent of days snow covered during the month (1.0 = 100%)";
grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic";
coordinates = "longitude latitude time";
valid_range = 0.0f, 1.0f; // float
_ChunkSizes = 1U, 88U, 88U; // uint
```

But somehow I am not able to get the polar stereographic shape. How can I do this? Is there any other software that can help me with this?

Comment: The grid_mapping attribute value indicates that there should be another variable in the file named "polar_stereographic", whose attributes specify the polar stereographic grid. Otherwise, you don't indicate what features it is that Panoply isn't giving you, so how can anyone suggest software that does?

Comment: Sorry if my question has not been very clear. I need to make polar stereographic maps. but when I use the map controls, I choose "stereographic" option but I still do not get the polar stereographic map. Also, I am not sure what it means when we have grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic" What does that imply? How can I take it into account when I am trying to map the data?

Comment: If the file follows the CF convention, then grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic" means that there is supposed to be another variable in the dataset named "polar_stereographic" and that the attributes of that other variable specify parameters about the stereographic projection that are necessary to understand the gridding. Without that added info, it's a guessing game. See Sect. 5.6 and Apx. E of http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.11/cf-conventions.html

Comment: BTW: You seem to be asking two questions, although it might seem you're only asking one. You have data that says it's on a polar stereographic grid, and understanding that is the first question. But you initially asked about the map controls for plotting it in Panoply which is the second question.